# is std::thread supported on MSVC 11?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, std

i wants to implement a cross platform multithreading program and read that std does support multithreading throug std::thread class but i am not sure if MSVC 11 does support it 
on this page 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx

it says about Concurreny Memory Model

> Memory model: N2429 made the Core Language recognize the existence of multithreading, but there appears to be nothing for a compiler implementation to do (at least, one that already supported multithreading).  So it's N/A in the table

but in the same time the thread header is indeed included in Visual studio 2012

so can anybody help me to realize to what context is std::thread supported in MSVC11

Comment: I can use `std::thread` perfectly fine in VS2012.

Comment: "there appears to be nothing for a compiler implementation to do (at least, one that already supported multithreading". The author could have said, "multi-threading, with a memory model that makes at least all of the guarantees that C++11 makes about avoiding data races". There could in principle be a C++03 implementation with a different memory model, that makes weaker guarantees, and then there would be work to do in that compiler. But C++11 was designed with existing (major) threading implementations in mind.

Comment: Also, I think the author is distinguishing between nothing for a *compiler* to do vs nothing to do in the libraries. So adding `<thread>` isn't a compiler change, as far as that author is concerned, and it's not part of the "memory model" line item. It's a library change. I think that for pretty much any C++03 implementation on which `boost::thread` was already implemented, you can implement `std::thread` too without compiler changes, just provide the right interface in the right header.

Comment: any way it is misleading !

Comment: @YamenAjjour No, it isn't, since the memory model didn't and doesn't have anything to do with the presence of `std::thread`. I don't even have any idea how you actually landed on this quote about the memory model when researching about the support for `std::thread`.

Comment: @ChristianRau please see "Multi-threaded executions and data races" in the Concurrency memory model in open-std http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2429.htm

Comment: @YamenAjjour Of course the memory model is related to multi-threading, but this is totally orthogonal to the actual library support for `std::thread`. They are just too more or less unrelated concepts. One is a compiler feature and the other a library feature. Ok, having `std::thread` present probably tells us that the implementation cares for multithreading and thus realizes the memory model. But on the other hand some statements about the memory model don't convey any information about support for `std::thread`.

Comment: so how do you suggest checking for actual library support for std::thread in MSVC 11 ?

Comment: @YamenAjjour It is just that noone would deduce information about supported library features from just a statement about a totally different compiler feature. That's why it is not misleading.

Comment: @YamenAjjour Well, that is a different question. But lack of possibilities doesn't make invalid possibilities magically valid. Just because I don't have a license for flying a plane, I won't try to fly with a car. The last (though not best, I admit) option in the end would be to write a small test program.

Comment: @YamenAjjour Or scroll down that post some sentences to the part where they state to try and implement a complete C++11 standard library (Ok, they actually didn't, but well) and that the `<thread>` header (and all the other MT headers) is new. Since `<thread>` doesn't really contain anything apart from `std::thread` you *might* be quite sure they support `std::thread` (and all the other facilities).

Comment: @ChristianRau: "having std::thread present probably tells us that the implementation cares for multithreading and thus realizes the memory model" -- although implementations can always pull a fast one on you, and make the threading header available always but only realize the memory model if you remember to compile with `-pthread` ;-)

Answer (score 8):

> it says about Concurreny Memory Model

The "Concurrency Memory Model" is *not* `std::thread`. The Concurrency Memory Model is language in the standard that explains how variables behave in the presence of threads. *Any* threads, whether they come from `std::thread` or OS threads or whatever.

Comment: Finally someone who gives a proper answer, explaining the initial problem problem of the question. +1

Comment: just to give an example, according to c++11 static variables in functions should be thread safe, but they are not in VC11 afaik.

Answer (score 5):

What it basically says is that MSVC already supported threading before, so there was nothing to do except add the Standard wrappers. So it's quite fine to use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but there are known bugs:
http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/news/just-thread-v1.8.0-released.html